# Success message alert after sending a mail successfully

Tags: php

The success message alert is not working...

**My code:**

```
$from="contactus@test.com.au";
$to = $email;
$subject = "Sign Up Mail verification ";
$message = 'test';

if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
    //echo "Your Account Activate will be Soon";
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Confirmation sent to your registered email. 
        Please check your inbox.");</script>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.assign("http://test.com.au/register/");
        </script>';
}
```

What is the problem with this code?

Comment: where is $headers which you have passed in mail function

Comment: `undefined headers variable` notice is what you should be getting thrown back

Comment: check alert by removing echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.assign("http://test.com.au/register/");</script>';